# Where is the standard java package located on the HDD?

Tags: java, package

When I do an import like this:

```
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
```

I can use the methods/fields from that Class. I'm just wondering where this package is actually located on my HDD.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on your system and your JRE emplacement.

On Mac OS it's in `/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Home/bundle/Classes/classes.jar`

On Windows or Linux in `$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/rt.jar` (thanks @kuropenguin for the information)
`$JAVA_HOME` depending on where you've installed your JDK.

On other systems, you'll have to look for yourself.

Comment: Small edit: the rt.jar file is in `$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/rt.jar` on Windows.

Comment: In Linux under the /usr/java/*/jre/lib/rt.jar

Comment: It depends on the bundle as well.  Even on my Mac, I usually use the Oracle distro (formerly Sun) which installed to the same place as Linux.  You really need to know which java distro you are running.

Comment: @dsmith, which distribution do you use ? I never saw a Mac version of the JDK provided by Sun/Oracle

Comment: MacPorts has a distro.  Now I think about it, it must have been openjdk6 that I installed on my Mac.  Sorry, most on my actual development I do on Linux.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the class present in Eclipse you kan find the physical placement in the Properties for the class.